# How to map values to a DataFrame with multiple columns as keys?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes like so:

```
    data = {'A': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
    data2 = {'A': [3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4, 20, 2], 'C':[5,3,2,1, 5, 1]}
    df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)
```

Now I did a groupby of df2 for C

```
values_to_map = df2.groupby(['A', 'B']).mean().to_dict()
```

Now I would like to map `df1['new C']` where the columns A and B match.

```
A   B   new_C
0   3   1   1.0
1   2   2   2.0
2   1   3   2.0
3   0   4   12.5
```

where new c is basically the averages of `C` for every pair `A, B` from `df2`

Note that A and B don't have to be keys of the dataframe (i.e. they aren't unique identifiers which is why I want to map it with a dictionary originally, but failed with multiple keys)

How would I go about that?

Thank you for looking into it with me!

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: @U12-Forward Apologies, I added it and I fixed a flaw in my initial proposal (non matching pairs)

Comment: Why is the last value `12.5`?

Comment: sorry the second last entry should be 20, I changed it. @U12-Forward

Comment: @U12-Forward like the desired output is basically .map but with two series instead of one? If that makes any sense?

Comment: Olli, I came up with a much better solution.

Comment: Your `apply` is slow, check my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `np.vectorize`:

```
values_to_map = df2.groupby(['A', 'B']).mean().to_dict()

df1['new_c'] = np.vectorize(lambda x: values_to_map.get(x['A'], x['B']))(df1[['A', 'B']])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's one of the first things I tried, with transforms etc. as well. I don't think it works if they're not the same length. And not unique, i.e. index can't be duplicates I.e. df1 has maybe 100's of pairs of 3,1

Comment: @Olli Ah, edited my answer, gotcha

Comment: hmm, I tried this exact line (transform) too, let me try again, edit: no, following error: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1

Comment: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1.
I think the issue is here, that for some pairs they don't exist in df2, but I may remedy that. I.e. all pairs in df2 exist in df1 but not all pairs of df1 are in df2

Comment: @Olli Ah then your way is the way to go.

Comment: @Olli Ah, check my most recent edit!

Comment: I did, thanks so much for your help, this may be the quickest way then

Comment: @Olli Yes! numpy functions are very quick :)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to this

```
values_to_map = df2.groupby(['A', 'B']).mean().to_dict()

df1['new_c'] = df1.apply(lambda x: values_to_map[x['A'], x['B']], axis=1)
```

Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: This almost works according to the data you shared in the question. I guess you need to pass `axis=1` to `apply` so that it works row-by-row (and `x` becomes a row in each turn). Also, it seems `["C"]` is needed to index `values_to_map` dictionary before `[x[...]`?

Comment: A note (maybe you already know but here it goes): neither pandas' `apply` nor `np.vectorize` are "vectorized" routines. However, they might be fast enough for one's purposes and might prove more readable in places. I think `apply` solution of yours is the most readable here (+1!). Still, I tried to write an answer from another perspective, hoping that it helps at all.

Comment: @MustafaAydın thank you for your comments and answer, yes, I need axis=1 here I will edit. Thank you for the confidence booster as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can first form a MultiIndex from the `[["A", "B"]]` subset of the frame `df1` and use *its* `map` function to map the A-B pairs to the desired grouped mean values:

```
cols = ["A", "B"]

mapper = df2.groupby(cols).C.mean()

df1["new_c"] = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1[cols]).map(mapper)
```

to get

```
>>> df1

   A  B  new_c
0  3  1    5.0
1  2  2    2.0
2  1  3    2.0
3  0  4    1.0
```

(if an A-B pair in `df1` isn't found in `df2`'s groups, `new_c` corresponding to that pair will be `NaN` with this method.)

---

Note that neither pandas' `apply` nor `np.vectorize` are "vectorized" routines. However, they might be fast enough for one's purposes and might prove more readable in places.

Comment: Thank you for this answer and note! That's very helpful to know as well. And it's better than my method! I ommited an else return np.nan clause for readability and brevity aboth, with yours I won't need that!